# filter array includes multiple items

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, include

i want to filter an array by some specific names

```
genres = [
{id: 1, name: 'Action'},
{id: 2, name: 'Comedy'},
{id: 3, name: 'Documentary'},
{id: 4, name: 'Action'},
{id: 5, name: 'Comedy'},
]

// in here i get only Action
genres.filter(i => i.name.includes("Action"))
output = [
{id: 1, name: 'Action'},
{id: 4, name: 'Action'},
]

// in here i get only Comedy
genres.filter(i => i.name.includes("Comedy"))
output = [
{id: 2, name: 'Comedy'},
{id: 5, name: 'Comedy'},
]
```

**But i want to get both Action and Comedy like this:**

```
[
{id: 1, name: 'Action'},
{id: 4, name: 'Action'},
{id: 2, name: 'Comedy'},
{id: 5, name: 'Comedy'},
]
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

`genres.filter(i => i.name.includes("Action") | i.name.includes("Comedy"))`

or

`genres.filter(i => ["Action","Comedy"].includes(i.name))`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use an OR operator to check on both conditions

```js
genres = [
{id: 1, name: 'Action'},
{id: 2, name: 'Comedy'},
{id: 3, name: 'Documentary'},
{id: 4, name: 'Action'},
{id: 5, name: 'Comedy'},
]

// Use a OR operator to check both conditions
result = genres.filter(i => i.name.includes("Action") || i.name.includes("Comedy"))


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const genres = [{id: 1, name: 'Action'},{id: 2, name: 'Comedy'},{id: 3, name: 'Documentary'},{id: 4, name: 'Action'},{id: 5, name: 'Comedy'},]

const result = genres.filter(({ name }) => ['Action', 'Comedy'].includes(name))

console.log(result)
```